# Second account for ESXi for NFS access only

Tags: nfs, esxi

is it possible to create a seperate user, and force ESXi to use that account for NFS access to NFS shares?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this for ESXi. NFS access requires the use of the root user (UID 0) to access NFS shares and you have to disable root_squash.

For ESX there is "experimental support" for delegating NFS access to a separate account, as per this [VMware document](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi301/server_config/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=server_config&file=sc_security_auth.16.8.html).  That's VMware code for saying the functionality is there but if you run it on production systems nobody is going to help you if anything goes wrong.